# Clicking a checkbox with ng-click does not update the model

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Clicking on a checkbox and calling ng-click: the model is not updated before ng-click kicks in so the checkbox value is wrongly presented in the UI:

This works in AngularJS 1.0.7 and seems broken in Angualar 1.2-RCx.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<li  ng-repeat="todo in todos">
  <input type='checkbox' ng-click='onCompleteTodo(todo)' ng-model="todo.done">
    {{todo.text}}
</li> 
<hr>
task: {{todoText}}
<hr><h2>Wrong value</h2>
     done: {{doneAfterClick}}
```

and controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.todos=[
        {'text': "get milk",
         'done': true
         },
        {'text': "get milk2",
         'done': false
         }
        ];


   $scope.onCompleteTodo = function(todo) {
    console.log("onCompleteTodo -done: " + todo.done + " : " + todo.text);
    $scope.doneAfterClick=todo.done;
    $scope.todoText = todo.text;

   };
}]);
```

Broken Fiddle w/ Angular 1.2 RCx
 - http://jsfiddle.net/supercobra/ekD3r/

Working fidddle w/ Angular 1.0.0 
 - http://jsfiddle.net/supercobra/8FQNw/

Comment: Also broken for me now that I've updated Angular to 1.2+

Comment: Also broken in v1.2.24.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

How about changing

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-click='onCompleteTodo(todo)' ng-model="todo.done">
```

to

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-change='onCompleteTodo(todo)' ng-model="todo.done">
```

From [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange):

> Evaluate given expression when user changes the input. The expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model.
>
> Note, this directive requires `ngModel` to be present.

Comment: this also seems to be broken in version 1.2.7

Comment: Holy lightbulb, Batman! I thought I was doing something else completely wrong, but it turned out to be as simple as this.

Comment: Very helpful answer! +1 Angular doc -1

Comment: what if you need the event data to preventDefault?

Answer (score 12):

As reported in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4765, switching from ng-click to ng-change seems to fix this (I am using Angular 1.2.14)

Comment: Simplest and easiest fix. +1 to Griffindor :)

Answer (score 9):

The order in which `ng-click` and `ng-model` will be executed is ambiguous (since neither explicitly set their `priority`). The most stable solution to this would be to avoid using them on the same element.

Also, you probably do not want the behavior that the examples show; you want the `checkbox` to respond to clicks on the complete *label text*, not only the checkbox. Hence, the cleanest solution would be to wrap the `input` (with `ng-model`) inside a `label` (with `ng-click`):

```
<label ng-click="onCompleteTodo(todo)">
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model="todo.done">
  {{todo.text}}
</label>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/b3NLH/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the only solution that worked to me!

Comment: This solution is still the best!

Answer (score 8):

Why dont you use

```
$watch('todo',function(.....
```

Or another solution would be to set the `todo.done` inside the ng-click callback and only use ng-click

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<li  ng-repeat="todo in todos">
<input type='checkbox' ng-click='onCompleteTodo(todo)'>
    {{todo.text}} {{todo.done}}
```

and

```
$scope.onCompleteTodo = function(todo) {
        todo.done = !todo.done; //toggle value
        console.log("onCompleteTodo -done: " + todo.done + " : " + todo.text);
        $scope.current = todo;
}
```

Comment: See @kakoni answer, I used ng-change instead of ng-click and the timing works great.  This lets you keep the two way binding and is much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 7):

Replacing ng-model with ng-checked works for me.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Just worked for me from all the available solutions here.

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of a hack but wrapping it in a timeout seems to accomplish what you are looking for:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.todos = [{
        'text': "get milk",
        'done': true
    }, {
        'text': "get milk2",
            'done': false
    }];

    $scope.onCompleteTodo = function (todo) {
        $timeout(function(){
            console.log("onCompleteTodo -done: " + todo.done + " : " + todo.text);
            $scope.doneAfterClick = todo.done;
            $scope.todoText = todo.text;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ordering between `ng-model` and `ng-click` seems to be different and it's something you probably shouldn't rely on. Instead you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<li  ng-repeat="todo in todos">
<input type='checkbox' ng-model="todo.done" ng-click='onCompleteTodo(todo)'>
    {{todo.text}} {{todo.done}}
</li> 
    <hr>
        task: {{current.text}}
        <hr>
            <h2>Wrong value</h2>
         done: {{current.done}}
</div>
```

And your script:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.todos=[
            {'text': "get milk",
             'done': true
             },
            {'text': "get milk2",
             'done': false
             }
            ];

        $scope.current = $scope.todos[0];


       $scope.onCompleteTodo = function(todo) {
            console.log("onCompleteTodo -done: " + todo.done + " : " + todo.text);
    //$scope.doneAfterClick=todo.done;
    //$scope.todoText = todo.text;
       $scope.current = todo;

   };
}]);
```

What's different here is whenever you click a box, it sets that box as what's "current" and then display those values in the view. http://jsfiddle.net/QeR7y/

Answer (score 0):

> Usually this is due to another directive in-between your ng-controller
>   and your input that is creating a new scope. When the select writes
>   out it value, it will write it up to the most recent scope, so it
>   would write it to this scope rather than the parent that is further
>   away.
>
> The best practice is to never bind directly to a variable on the scope
>   in an `ng-model`, this is also known as always including a "dot" in
>   your ngmodel. For a better explanation of this, check out this video
>   from John:
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc

Solution from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7Nd_me5YrHU

Comment: It'd be great if you provide a jump marker `#t=5m08s` in your YouTube link so it's not necessary to watch the full video. See http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/link-to-youtube-minute-second/

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced `ng-model` with `ng-checked` and it worked for me.

This issue was when I updated my angular version from `1.2.28` to `1.4.9`

Also check if your `ng-change` is causing any issue here. I had to remove my `ng-change` as-well to make it working.

Answer (score -1):

```
.task{ng:{repeat:'task in model.tasks'}}
  %input{type:'checkbox',ng:{model:'$parent.model.tasks[$index].enabled'}}
```