# What changed with AngularJS 1.2.0-rc.3 that stops ng-click from having the right model value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

We have some code in an `ng-click` that broke with version 1.2.0-rc.3 because the value in the scope hasn't been updated from the click. Here's a dumbed down version:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll" ng-click="allChecked()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check4"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check5"/>
    <p/>
    All: {{checkAll}}<br/>
    1: {{check1}}<br/>
    2: {{check2}}<br/>
    3: {{check3}}<br/>
    4: {{check4}}<br/>
    5: {{check5}}<br/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.allChecked = function() {
        console.log($scope.checkAll);
        if ($scope.checkAll)
        {

            $scope.check1 = true;
            $scope.check2 = true;
            $scope.check3 = true;
            $scope.check4 = true;
            $scope.check5 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.check1 = false;
            $scope.check2 = false;
            $scope.check3 = false;
            $scope.check4 = false;
            $scope.check5 = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle with 1.2.0-rc.2: http://jsfiddle.net/73E26/

Now with the same exact setup for 1.2.0-rc.3 (http://jsfiddle.net/LZR6j/), it now longer works as expected. `$scope.checkAll` is false, even though it is checked. So, the model isn't getting updated before the click listener is called like it was with 1.2.0-rc.2. What changed that is causing this? I've found that I can make this work by using `ng-change` instead of `ng-click` (http://jsfiddle.net/8VV7N/), but I want to understand what is going on so I base future decisions on it. Can anyone shed some light this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [`ng-click`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L44) and [`ng-model`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1201) have [ambiguous *priority*](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) and if you define them on the same element, it is unclear in what order will they be fired.

See this question for instance: [Clicking a checkbox with ng-click does not update the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496821/clicking-a-checkbox-with-ng-click-does-not-update-the-model)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So what's the difference between `ng-click` and `ng-change` that makes `ng-change` work? Or is it just by chance that it is working like `ng-click` was?

Comment: I would guess that it was by chance that they were working, or perhaps because `ng-change` sets a `$watch` on the `expression` for `ng-model` and that `$watch` is fired only after `ng-model` has processed the value (setting it to the correct value `false`). However, in my experience, it is best to avoid such arrangements.