# ng-click only works if I don't have a model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have this code in my file

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><a ng-click="sort('PartnerName')">@TID.Partner</a></th>
                        <th><a ng-click="sort('StartTID')">@TID.StartTID</a></th>
                        <th><a ng-click="sort('EndTID')">@TID.EndTID</a></th>
                        <th><a ng-click="sort('DateBlocked')">@TID.DateBlocked</a></th>
                        <th><a ng-click="sort('Blocked')">@TID.Blocked</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortOrder:reverseSort | filter:refine | filter: { 'Blocked': showInactive!==true } as filtered ">
                        <td>{{ item.PartnerName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.StartTID }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.EndTID }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.DateBlocked }}</td>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="UnBlockOne(item);" ng-model="item.Blocked"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-if="processed == false" ng-cloak>
                        <td colspan="5">@TID.Loading</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-if="filtered.length == 0 && processed == true" ng-cloak>
                        <td colspan="5">@TID.NoResultsFound</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I have this checkbox

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="UnBlockOne(item);" ng-model="item.Blocked"/></td>
```

that calls this method in my controller

```
   $scope.UnBlockOne = function (item) {
        db.UnBlockOne(item, function () {
            $scope.GetFilteredList(filter);
            $rootScope.processed = true;
        });
    };
```

The strange thing is that the ng-click does not work if I have a ng-model.

So, this works

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="UnBlockOne(item);" ng-model=""/></td>
```

And this does not work

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="UnBlockOne(item);" ng-model="item.Blocked"/></td>
```

I have code just like this in other files and it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking a checkbox with ng-click does not update the model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496821/clicking-a-checkbox-with-ng-click-does-not-update-the-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at ng-change rather than ng-click

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, I am not sure as I cannot test it:

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="UnBlockOne('item');" ng-model="item.Blocked"/></td>

 $scope.UnBlockOne = function (item) {
        db.UnBlockOne($scope['item'], function () {
            $scope.GetFilteredList(filter);
            $rootScope.processed = true;
        });
    };
```

However for checkboxes you should use ng-change.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-click use ng-change.

Ref : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D